# What's the Linux equivalent of Window's GetAsyncKeyState?

Tags: c++, linux, keyboard

I'm using c++, and I need to determine if a shift key is pressed. In windows, I can just use GetAsyncKeyState. How can I do this in Linux?
I cannot run as root.

Answer (score 1):

Under X Windows, you can load the X Keyboard extension and call `XkbGetState()` to get the current keyboard state.  If the shift key is being pressed, the `base_mods` field of the `XkbStateRec` structure set by `XkbGetState()` will have the `ShiftMask` bit set.  Full documentation here: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/XKB/xkblib.html#Determining_Keyboard_State

That is a synchronous call, but you can instead request to be sent `XkbEvent` events whenever certain aspects of the keyboard state change, by calling `XkbSelectEventDetails()`.  There are several other ways you could receive keyboard events asynchronously, but here, you are interested in when the Shift key is pressed or released, which is reported as a bitmask in a field of modifiers.

Alternatively: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225290/4474419