# Get Key state C++ Linux

Tags: c++, tui

I have a small game which requires 4 Keys: 2 Keys to move the Player to the left/right, 1 Key to accelerate horzontal movement (dash key), and 1 Key to move vertically faster.

You can find the current project at https://github.com/jonlit/spacestarprocessing (The game idea was from my teacher, he put a task in a class test where we should complete UML diagrams and some code for the classes).
I'm trying to rewrite it as a TUI game.
I found that on Windows there is GetKeyState(), but I haven't found anything similar for Linux.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649874/how-can-i-get-the-keyboard-state-in-linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the keyboard state in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649874/how-can-i-get-the-keyboard-state-in-linux)